# How to setup heroku app locally using docker?

Tags: heroku, docker, boot2docker, docker-compose, heroku-postgres

I am trying to setting up heroku app locally using docker which is developed using java (Dropwizard framework) and postgresql.

Following this guidelines : https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/docker

Getting docker-machine ip using (changed port to 2204 in docker-compose.yml file)

```
$ docker-compose up
$open "http://$(docker-machine ip default):2204"
```

Issue: Unable to access local server ping api - http://docker-machine-ip:port/ping

```
Other details:
OS X El Capitan 10.11.1 (15B42)
Docker version 1.9.0, build 76d6bc9
heroku-toolbelt/3.42.25 (x86_64-darwin10.8.0) ruby/1.9.3
heroku-cli/4.27.9-cce0260 (amd64-darwin) go1.5.2
=== Installed Plugins
 heroku-apps@1.0.0
 heroku-cli-addons@0.1.1
 heroku-docker@1.1.2
 heroku-fork@4.0.0
 heroku-git@2.4.4
 heroku-local@4.1.5
 heroku-run@2.9.2
 heroku-status@1.2.4
```

Thanks!

Comment: Unable to access local server running on docker - https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/19096

Answer (score 0):

Is `docker-machine` installed and on your PATH?

From what you've written (`http://:port/ping`) it looks like you aren't getting the IP address, which implies that `docker-machine ip default` is returning nothing.

Like so:

```
$ echo "http://$(docker-machine ip default):2204"
-bash: docker-machine: command not found
http://:2204
```

See https://docs.docker.com/machine/install-machine/ for installation of docker-machine.

Comment: yes, docker-machine installed. 
```$ docker-machine ip default ```
output: ```192.168.99.100```